# Plugging in values in sympy and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I am wondering how I can input values into my Matrix (J*f). Specifically, I need to plug in the values from my p matrix => p[0,0] = the x value, p[0,1] = the y value, p[0,2] = the z value (This is the first iteration however the values will change after each iteration). The reason I am doing it this way is because I need to make a loop of 5 iterations.

p inital matrix looks likes this but in a column not a row
[0.1,
 0.1,
-0.1]

How can I go around doing this?

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np


x, y, z = sp.symbols("x y z")


eq1 = 3*x - sp.cos(y*z) - 1/2
eq2 = x**2 -81*(y+0.1)**2 + sp.sin(z) + 1.06
eq3 = sp.exp(-x*y) + 20*z + (10*sp.pi - 3)/3

A = np.array([[0,0,x],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])

f = np.array([[eq1],[eq2],[eq3]])

A[0,0] = sp.diff(eq1,x)
A[1,0] = sp.diff(eq1,y)
A[2,0] = sp.diff(eq1,z)
A[0,1] = sp.diff(eq2,x)
A[1,1] = sp.diff(eq2,y)
A[2,1] = sp.diff(eq2,z)
A[0,2] = sp.diff(eq3,x)
A[1,2] = sp.diff(eq3,y)
A[2,2] = sp.diff(eq3,z)


J = sp.Matrix(A).inv()

p = np.array([[0.1], [0.1], [-0.1]])

p = p - J*f 
i = 0
for i in range(0,4):
    p = p - J*f 
    i += 1
print(p)
```

Comment: Up till `J` this your previous question/answers.  So what is working or not?  Itried to show some intermediate results (`J` is too large) and at least one error.  Take that as a model of what you should be showing us.

Comment: Could you simplify the example, say to a (2,2) matrix with only 1 equation?  It would be easier to display and discuss.

Comment: Everything is working I just need to figure out the loop.

To be more clear I need to put in the values from the p matrix into the J and F matrix. Use the equation (p = J*f -p) to calculate the next p matrix. After calculating the new p matrix I need to put in the next values into the J and F matrix functions again. 

Do this all 5 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `Matrix(A)` from my answer to your previous question:

```
In [23]: As                                                                                            
Out[23]: 
⎡                               -x⋅y⎤
⎢    3            2⋅x       -y⋅ℯ    ⎥
⎢                                   ⎥
⎢                               -x⋅y⎥
⎢z⋅sin(y⋅z)  -162⋅y - 16.2  -x⋅ℯ    ⎥
⎢                                   ⎥
⎣y⋅sin(y⋅z)     cos(z)         20   ⎦
```

Using `subs` to replace `x,y,z` with numbers:

```
In [24]: As.subs({x:0.1, y:0.1, z:-0.1})                                                               
Out[24]: 
⎡          3                   0.2         -0.0990049833749168⎤
⎢                                                             ⎥
⎢0.000999983333416667         -32.4        -0.0990049833749168⎥
⎢                                                             ⎥
⎣-0.000999983333416667  0.995004165278026          20         ⎦
```

and taking the sympy inv:

```
In [25]: _.inv()                                                                                       
Out[25]: 
⎡ 0.333333183973692   0.0021086068381224    0.0016605204461288  ⎤
⎢                                                               ⎥
⎢1.0238518631053e-5   -0.0308688255197139  -0.000152757694650781⎥
⎢                                                               ⎥
⎣1.61570129882115e-5  0.00153583592705254   0.0500076827517613  ⎦
```

Same thing if I do `subs` on `J=As.inv()`:

```
In [26]: J.subs({x:0.1, y:0.1, z:-0.1})                                                                
Out[26]: 
⎡ 0.333333183973692   0.0021086068381224    0.0016605204461288  ⎤
⎢                                                               ⎥
⎢1.0238518631053e-5   -0.0308688255197139  -0.000152757694650782⎥
⎢                                                               ⎥
⎣1.61570129882115e-5  0.00153583592705254   0.0500076827517613  ⎦
```

`J*f` is still a sympy matrix (`J` is sympy, `f` is ndarray), so subs works here to:

```
In [27]: (J*f).subs({x:0.1, y:0.1, z:-0.1})                                                            
Out[27]: 
⎡-0.39071797440964 ⎤
⎢                  ⎥
⎢0.0687621665029634⎥
⎢                  ⎥
⎣0.419660799608434 ⎦
```

(if probably would be better if `f` were sympy matrix, but as I noted before, sometimes sympy objects in an object dtype array do work.)

(I'm doing these calcs in an `isympy` session.)

Comment: Doesn't work gives the error:

A.subs([(x, p[0,0]), (y, p[1,0]), (z, p[2,0])])
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'subs'

here is my code:
https://pastebin.com/Kci48R8Y

Comment: `subs` can only be used on sympy objects.

Comment: In reference to your next question, note that I am displaying the result of the `subs` call, not the original `J` etc.  `subs` does not operate in-place.